# Issue with scroll animation on load

Tags: javascript, scroll, jquery-animate

This is the [fiddle](https://codepen.io/guioman/pen/edoCh) I have used on my website.

Everything is fine except the image jerks on load when viewing on Mozilla.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
var imgCounter = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pictureCount = $('#container img').length;
    var scrollResolution = 50;

    animateHorse();

    function animateHorse() {
        var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
        var imageIndex = Math.round(currentScrollPosition / scrollResolution);

        if (imageIndex >= pictureCount) {
            imageIndex = pictureCount - 1; // Select last image
        }
        else{
            //imageIndex    =   0;
        }

        console.log(imageIndex);
        //if($("#container img").is(":visible"))
        $("#container img").hide();
        $("#container img").eq(imageIndex).show();
        $("#container").css("position","relative");
        $("#container").css("margin-bottom","150px");
        $(".lastdivcar").css("display","none");
    }

    $(document).bind('scroll', function() {
        animateHorse();
    });
});
</script>
```